# Microsoft ODBC Query for excluding a specific value from the column

Tags: sql, excel, odbc, uipath

I converted an Excel Workbook into a database using ODBC Data Sources.

Used the Run Query Activity in UiPath under the  Database Activities and tried to extract data from the Excel in a particular column excluding a specific value in this case it is zero.
Below is the query I tried  to use but it returns the

```
"SELECT * FROM [Export Worksheet$] WHERE NOT CStr(INT_RECV_CLOSING_BAL)= '0';"
```

Am getting an error of:

```
Run query: ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Syntax error in string in query expression
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax should be where *column name* meets requirement or you can use IN(*value*) or NOT IN(*value*)

Try using the below to see if they work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Export Worksheet$]
WHERE CStr(INT_RECV_CLOSING_BAL) != '0';

SELECT *
FROM [Export Worksheet$]
WHERE CStr(INT_RECV_CLOSING_BAL) <> '0';
```

Comment: Thanks @cmnardi
I solved the problem by changing the service provider for the connection string and it resolved the issue.